# Fetch data from IndexedDB in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, indexeddb

**Anyone knows about Angular2 IndexedDb.Please help me.**

I have a json response like this.

```
{
  "response": {
    "data": {
      "name": "ABC",
      "Id": "1234",
      "address": "adthhyrr"    
    }
  }
}
```

I am saving this response to IndexedDB. But i am facing problem while fetching data from indexedDB.
I am following this example.https://github.com/robisim74/angular2indexedDB

In the service file am doing like this to get data.

```
 getAllData(): any {  

       return new Promise(resolve => 
          {
            this.indexedDB.openDBAsync("Angular2IndexedDB", 1).forEach(

                (readyState: string) => {

                    console.log('IndexedDB service: opening db: ' + readyState);

                }, null

            ).then(

                () => {

                    // Gets all records from "Table".
                    this.indexedDB.getAllRecordsAsync("Login").forEach(

                        // Next.
                        (record: Todo) => {
                            if (record != null) {
                               this.indexeddb_data = JSON.parse(record.description);
                                console.log('data'+this.indexeddb_data);
                               //here am getting data in this.indexeddb_data.In console i am getting.
                                return this.indexeddb_data;
                            }
                        }, null

                    ).then(() => {

                        resolve(true);
                        return this.indexeddb_data;

                    });

                });
        });
    }
```

But it is not returning anything.Can anyone please me how to do this.Or any other method is there to fetch data from IndexedDB?

Answer (score 0):

Where you're referencing "this.indexedDB", the author of the linked code actually has functions on his service object that handle the "openDBAsync" functionality and the getAllRecordsAsync functionality. They're not functions on the indexedDB object. So, if you've declared functions on your service like he has or are importing them from some other service, then you should reference them in the correct way. If they're declared directly on the service class, then just say "this.openDBAsync('some_name', 1)" instead of how you've done it. And if you're importing these functions from some other file, then just call them directly like this "openDBAsync('some_name', 1)".

Also, take a look at the indexedDB api to make sure you have the available methods down, so you don't get tripped up. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API